# MySQL -- "Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a series of tables for a hospital database, and whenever i try to run the code, i get an error saying "Error Code 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint." I've done a lot of research to see what i've done wrong, but i cant figure it out. What's wrong with my foreign keys?
Here are the relevant tables. Thanks.

```
create table Patient(
num int(8),
Fname varchar(20),
Lname varchar(20),
SSN char(11),
dateofBirth date,   
primary key(num)
);

create table Department(
Description varchar(250),
DepCode char(3),
DepName varchar(15),
Supervisor int(8),  
building char(6),
primary key(DepCode),
constraint fk_supervisor foreign key(Supervisor) references Employee(ID)
);  

create table Employee(
ID int(8),
Fname varchar(20),
Lname varchar(20),
SSN char(11),
Specialty varchar(15),
dateofHire date,
primary key(ID)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table (or column) that does not exist *cannot* be schema referenced.

Create the Employee table before the Department table - or add the constraint later, after all tables have been created, with [ALTER TABLE .. ADD FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Example corrected ordering:

```
create table Patient ..
create table Employee ..
create table Department ..
```